# How to present a separate View Controller when click on a button inside a custom TableViewCell Swift 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift4

I have 2 view controller,`MainVC` and `PopUpVC`. `MainVC` have a `tableView` with `tableViewCell` class.Every cell have a `ShowButton`.So what I want to do is,when I click on `ShowButton`,`PopUpVC` will show on top of `MainVc`

What I already do:

**1)** Connect `MainVC` and `PopUpVC` with segue of present modally,at the same time set the segue identifier to "popVc".

**2)** Set `PopUpVC` **Transition Style = Cover Vertical** and **Presentation = Over Current Context**  , Background of `PopUpVC` I set to **Clear Color** in StoryBoard.

**3)** In TableViewCell class for the TableView,set up the protocol and delegate like below :

```
    //here is MyTableViewCell class
protocol MyDelegate : class {
    func showPopUpVc(itemId: Int)
}

class MyTableCell : UITableViewCell {

    weak var delegate : MyDelegate?


    @IBAction func showButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        self.delegate?.showPopUpVc(itemId : MyItem.id)
    }
 }

 //View Controller 
class MainViewController: UIViewController ,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate , MyDelegate {

    func showPopVc(itemId; Int) {
        //here I want to show the PopUpVC
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popVc", sender: self)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyTableCell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableCell
      cell.items = self.items[indexPath.row]
      cell.delegate = self
      return cell
}

}
```

**4)** So inside `showPopVc()` function in `MainViewController` I tried this 2 solution in order to show the `popUpVC`

```
//1st solution
func showPopVc(itemId; Int) { 
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popVc", sender: self)
}

//2nd solution
func showPopVc(itemId; Int) { 
   let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let PopUpVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpVc")
    self.present(PopupVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Output that I get now :**

Whenever I tap the `ShowButton`, the tap is detected(Cause I set `print("Clicked")` in `showPopUpVc()`), but the whole screen become black.None of the content in `PopUpVC` is shown on the screen.Just black.Cant go back to previous screen,cause is absolutely black and blank screen

Both solution in section 4 also produce the same output.

So what I missing here? Or can somebody show me a complete example to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "popVc")
    {

         let newVC = segue.destination;

        self.setPresentationStyleForSelfController(selfController: self,presentingController: newVC)


    }

 }

 func setPresentationStyleForSelfController(selfController:UIViewController,presentingController:UIViewController)
{
   if #available(iOS 8.0, *)
    {

        //iOS 8.0 and above

        presentingController.providesPresentationContextTransitionStyle = true;

        presentingController.definesPresentationContext = true;

        presentingController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext

    }
    else
    {

         presentingController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext

        selfController.navigationController?.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.currentContext
    }

}
```

Comment: set the background color of the popup to transparent from storyboard with //1st solution

Comment: I already set background of the `popUpVc` to Clear Color in StoryBoard

Comment: and the downvote is not from me ya..tq for your help

Comment: check your popup viewDidLoad you may altering background color or doing a return statement

Comment: my PopVc viewDidLoad is nothing inside. the PopVc currently only have a IBaction of a button which dismiss the PopVc,nothing else

Comment: re check segue name

Comment: Hey bro is it calling the `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popVc", sender: self)` in `showPopVc()` as usual and just add your code in MainVc` ? Is it like this?

Comment: bro I tried.Add all your code.then perform segue.but the screen still blank.identifier correct,segue "Present modally" in storyboard.The screen is still BLACK. just black.

Comment: My background of PopVc is clear color,inside it have just 1 button.I dont know why it is just black?

Comment: can u embed the mainvc in navigationcontroller and try

Comment: I embeded mainVc to navigationController.Is still black screen...Any possible reason why the screen is black when performSegue?

Comment: the popup is black or only the background color of it

Comment: popupVc background is Clear Color.Have a button inside.I have assign PopUpViewController to popUpVc in storyboard.Now when click the button.The screen is totally BLACK.nothing inside it.just black

Comment: is there any content in the popup screen ??? , change background color of popup say green and see what the result will be

Comment: I change the background color of PopVc to blue,I click the button,the screen is black just like I show u before

Comment: ok try to change color of the view in viewDidappear method of the popup

Comment: I change background color in ViewDidAppear in popUpVc by this code `backgroundView.backgroundColor = .red` ,by this the button tapped is detected,but it doesnt change anything.No popUpVc comming up.screen doesnt change anything.Just remain mainVc

Comment: try ->         self.view.backgroundColor = .red

Comment: having this error when click on the button `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: search for any ! and print that value to see if it's nil

Answer (score 0):

Set modal presentation style for view controller.

Try this and see (may this would work, programatically that one is not working with storyboard segue.):

```
func showPopVc(itemId; Int) { 
   let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let PopUpVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PopUpVc")

    // Try anyone of these according to your requirement.
    PopUpVc.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext
    //PopUpVc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

    self.present(PopupVc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: bro I tried your code,but once click on the button,the whole screen still black.I checked the identifier of my PopUpVc,is correct.Dont know why this happen

Comment: PopUpVc is a viewController. MainVc and PopUpVc both a View Controller.and dont have any NavigationController involved

Comment: I connect the MainVc and PopVc with segue present modally,set the identifier of the segue with "popVc" this one I checked many time. So I use `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popVc", sender: self)` ,black screen.The identifier I already triple checked is "popVc" dont know whats wrong

Comment: I attach the present modally segue from MainVc to PopUpVc.View controller to view controller

Comment: Ok I do it now..5 minutes please

Comment: I drag a new view controller in storyboard,then drag the "Show" segue from MainVc to NewViewController,set identifier to "justShowVc",use this code `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "justShowVc", sender: self)` inside `showPopVc()`,once I tapped the button,it still black.Dont know why is this happen..But `show` and `present modally` also have the same result.Black screen

Comment: In my project I have swiftsoup,alamofire and also swiftyJson.is this the framework you refer to?